# Is it possible to scale the UI and text of Chrome browser without scaling the images and videos?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, dpi

My Windows DPI scaling is set to 125% and Chrome obeys this rule. No issues whatsoever in that regard.

On Windows 7, the photo viewer app does exactly what I'm looking for - It scales its interphase (text and graphic elements) but leaves the images it is displaying at 1:1 scale. For example, a 20x10px photo will always take up 20x10 pixels on the display no matter what DPI it is set to. You can zoom in and out if you want of course.

Chrome's "page-zoom" feature scales everything. This is ok for text and vector graphics, but the images and videos become a bit blurry. There is a CSS trick that changes the upscaling algorithm used by Chrome to a slightly better one, but it doesn't seem to do much.

Comment: [Change text, image and video sizes (zoom) - Google Chrome Help](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/96810?hl=en-GB)